# How to structure multiple dashboards?

Tags: laravel

Lets say I have an "admin dashboard", "student dashboard" and "teacher dashboard".

Each dashboard has it own business logic.

I was thinking of structuring it like this:

```
|- app/  
   |- Console/  
      |- Commands/  
   |- Events/  
   |- Exceptions/  
   |- Http/  
      |- Controllers/  
          |- Admin/
          |- student/
          |- teacher/
      |- Middleware/  
   |- Jobs/  
   |- Listeners/  
   |- Providers/  
   |- Models
       |- User.php \\ can be admin - student - teacher
       |- Lesson.php
       |- Article.php
       |- Role.php \\ admin role - student role - teacher role 
       |- Permission.php
|- database/  
   |- factories/  
   |- migrations/  
   |- seeders  
|- config/  
|- routes/  
   |- admin/  
   |- student/
   |- teacher/
|- resources/  
   |- assets/  
   |- lang/  
   |- views/
```

but I don't know, this can seems messy to me, since the app will be more and more bigger in the future. I am looking for something that can be maintainable and when I want to change something or add some new feature I know where to look.

What the best practice to structure folders and files for this app?

Comment: Maybe you should separate your logic from roles and maintain role permissions in policies?

Comment: @Harven Actualy I will be using Laratrust package for managing roles and permissions. But that's not what my post is about.I am asking for a good way to structure my folders and files. ( As example ) Is it a good idea to structure it as Modules ? and how to do that?. So, I am just asking for better ways to structure my app as whole.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Access Control List (ACL) you can find some related packages like [Zizaco Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)
This helps in Access Control for accessing Admin Dashboard by Students and making other similar approaches.